# How to find custom MonoBehaviour scripts referred by unity3d GameObject by disunity or UnityStudio?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

Unity asset file format is very interesting, and I am reading **[disunity](https://github.com/ata4/disunity)** and **[UnityStudio](https://github.com/RaduMC/UnityStudio)** now, both are great open source projects to uncover the Unity3d asset files, but still has no clue how to find the custom monobehaviour scripts attached in a GameObject, UnityStudio can read GameObjects in an asset file and form a GameObject tree successfully, but all Components(including custom MonoBehaviour scripts) are saved as a PPtr (only 2 hash), how to find the script name and the other info?

```
public class PPtr
{
    //m_FileID 0 means current file
    public int m_FileID = -1;
    //m_PathID acts more like a hash in some games
    public long m_PathID = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no author email of 2 projects, so it is impossible to ask the author directly, maybe some guy on great Stackoverflow can helps me, :)

Comment: I assume the assetbundles are project-specific, so I guess the `m_FileID` and `m_PathID` are mapped to scripts INSIDE the project, not assetbundle. So unless you have the project most probably you won't be able to make any progress. I'm just guessing here, maybe someone more experienced can help you further

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think you are right, assembly types are global data, and maybe I should post my question on Unity forum.